# Error when making a simple boxplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the mpg data in R, I can make a boxplot of 'displ' with

```
boxplot(mpg$displ)
```

But when I try to make this simple boxplot with ggplot,

```
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(displ)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I get this error;

```
Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 'from' must be of length 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)? 
2: In is.na(data$y) :  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ggplot2` requires both an `x` and `y` variable of a boxplot. Here is how to make a single boxplot

```
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = "", y = displ)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
```